# Hard Parse on Non-Identical Statements?

Tags: oracle, parse

Let's say I have this query :

```
SELECT X FROM Y
```

If I run it for the first time then it would do a hard parse.

After that, I run this query :

```
select x from y
```

With just a difference in alphabetical upper and lower case, does it mean they have to do the hard parse again?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those are two different queries. They'll both be parsed and saved in the SQL area independently.

```
SQL> create table share_test (foobar number);
Table created.

SQL> select foobar from share_test;
no rows selected

SQL> SELECT foobar FROM SHARE_TEST;
no rows selected

SQL> select sql_id, sql_text from v$sqlarea where sql_text like '%foobar%';
SQL_ID
-------------
SQL_TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
g9cdv3mpuhd8d
select sql_id, sql_text from v$sqlarea where sql_text like '%foobar%'

d2v4u39j41y6k
select foobar from share_test

fdsqytc1y3f4u
SELECT foobar FROM SHARE_TEST
```

The criteria for SQL sharing are in the [Configuring and Using Memory](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/memory.htm) - [SQL Sharing Criteria](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/memory.htm#i40017) docs. Among others:

> The text of the SQL statements or PL/SQL blocks must be identical, character for character, including spaces, **case**, and comments.